# How to create excel table from parent-child table with php?

Tags: php, excel, data-structures, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have a classic parent child table like this

[image: parent-child table]

I want to show them like this on excel file

[image]

I have no problem with creating excel file i am using PhpSpreadsheet but i have problems with creating required data structure though. Can someone help ?

Edit : I fixed my problem with adding path enumaration and depth columns to my table i used depth for creating fixed arrays and i exploded paths then i looped through array which explode function gave me and then i filled my main array with elements of that array.[image]

Comment: I would look into [recursion](https://cjhaas.com/2019/10/25/mysql-recursive-cte/). The query is a little ugly, and it can be hard to understand what is really going on at first, but if you walk through it slowly it will hopefully make sense. In my sample, I'm using `null` to represent the parent, but you'd just change yours to `0`.

Comment: Thank you for answer i am using 5.7 version of MySQL so CTE is not an option for me is there a subquery version of that query ?

Comment: I usually favor queries over working with php arrays, but since you’ll no doubt be building the spreadsheet from an array, you could alternatively make a recursive function or class to order the data to mimic the layout of the spreadsheet. I’ll see if I can put something together…

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the ability to run a CTE, you *might* be able to get by with a bunch of sub queries, assuming your depth is finite and know.

Using the same database and data from my CTE example (with one extra row added):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
   EmployeeId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ParentEmployeId int NULL,
   Name varChar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ParentEmployeId) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId)
);

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (1, NULL, 'Company President 1');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (2, NULL, 'Company President 2');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (3, 1, 'Company President 1 - VP');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (4, 2, 'Company President 2 - VP');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (5, 3, 'Company President 1 - VP - Secretary');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (6, 4, 'Company President 2 - VP - Secretary');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (7, 5, 'Company President 1 - VP - Secretary - Sandwich Delivery');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (8, 1, 'Company President 1 - VP2');
```

You could use a query such as this:

```sql
SELECT
    E0.EmployeeId,
    E0.Name,
    E1.Name,
    E2.Name,
    E3.Name
FROM
    employees E0
LEFT JOIN
    employees E1
ON
    E0.EmployeeId = E1.ParentEmployeId
LEFT JOIN
    employees E2
ON
    E1.EmployeeId = E2.ParentEmployeId
LEFT JOIN
    employees E3
ON
    E2.EmployeeId = E3.ParentEmployeId
WHERE
    E0.ParentEmployeId IS NULL
;
```

Which produces the following data:

---

| EmployeeId | Name | Name | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company President 1 | Company President 1 - VP | Company President 1 - VP - Secretary | Company President 1 - VP - Secretary - Sandwich Delivery |
| 1 | Company President 1 | Company President 1 - VP2 |  |  |
| 2 | Company President 2 | Company President 2 - VP | Company President 2 - VP - Secretary |  |

If your data is not finite or you don't know at the time of the query the depth, you might have to jump through a bunch more hoops.

Comment: Thank you Chris i fixed my problem by another way but your answers gave me too much insight.